# How to resolve status code: 410 from Pagespeed insights for the wordpress website

Tags: plugins, errors, server, responsive, testing

I activate the plugin Seraphinite Accelerator on the website “http://tangentconsulting.ca”. After the activation, I changed the URL from our-story-2 to our-story. The Our Story page was working fine but when I checked the page speed insights, it gave the error “Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 410)”

Want to resolve this (Status code: 410). If pagespeed insights already saved the URL of our-story on its server-side cache, how long it will take to remove or update the previous server-side cache?

Comment: I'd never heard of that plugin before but after checking it out, most of what it does is just stuff you can/should already be doing yourself without using that plugin and the rest you can get from using a good WordPress host.

Comment: @TonyDjukic I got you. However, after deactivating this plugin, I got the same error (status code:410) for the our-story page. How we can resolve this? If this is just a cache issue, it should have been resolved now as I checked it today after almost a week.

Comment: Can you change the page slug back?

Comment: I did it. With the old URL "our-story-2", It is working fine. But you can see that including a 2 at the end of the URL, it looks bad.

Comment: @TonyDjukic if there is any other solution or useful plugin you know about, kindly share with me.

Comment: If the page actually works when you change it to `our-story` and it's just Google's Pagespeed Insights tool that's not finding it, then the issue isn't really something you can address outright.  Request a re-indexing from Search Console, check your site to see if there's any redirect plugin, check if Yoast has set-up a redirect.  Ultimately you can only control what your site does and if it works, it works.